# eclipse trying to load a class that does not exist anymoe

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I have a big project and i decided to change some of the packages inside and also rename and delete some classes.
After I did it I am getting an error of:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.Ser_Network`.

That class does not exist anymore and i have replaced it with a different class and changed all the references to it inside the project.
I have also tried `Project --> Clean`.

Nothing works and i don't know what else i can do.

### EDIT

I created a brand new project, created new packages and new class file (same names) and i am still getting this error.

How can i solve this issue? This is very important, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: seems like some classes still refering to Main.Ser_Network and you already delete/renaming?

Comment: When exactly do you get this execption? During startup of your application main method?

Comment: I am having this error when i reach some method in my project that used to load the `Ser_Network` class.

Comment: What is delete/renaming?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all references to the class are not in your code. You can do this by searching for it with a Ctrl+H.
Also try right-clicking your project folder and clicking "Close Project." Then try re-opening your project and rebuilding.

Comment: Can you check and see if there are any issues/errors with your build path?

Comment: How do i do that? When i look at the project explorer everything is fine over there. No red markers.

Comment: Right click your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Libraries Tab. Check and see if there are any errors here. If that doesn't work, try going to the problems tab (Windows -> Show View -> Problems) and deleting all the problems there if any.